# How can I put an input element on the same line as its label?

Tags: html, css

I would like to put a `label` and an `input[type=text]` on the same line, and I would like for the `input`'s width to fill the remaining width of the containing element, regardless of the length of the label's text (see first image).

I tried to use `width: auto;` for the `input`, but it seems to have a static width. I also tried `width: 100%;`, but that moves the `input` to a new line (see second image).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8rKG.jpg]

How can I achieve this using CSS?

Comment: What about using JavaScript? Is this valid option?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I came here looking for a replacement for my javascript solution.

Comment: @TomášZato cheers, so you found one?

Comment: It is crazy that this is so hard to do in 2022...

Answer (score 89, accepted):

It's possible without JavaScript, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Khmhk/

This works in IE7+ and all modern browsers.

**HTML:**

```
<label for="test">Label</label>
<span><input name="test" id="test" type="text" /></span>
```

**CSS:**

```
label {
    float: left
}
span {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 4px 0 6px
}
input {
    width: 100%
}
```

The reason why `overflow: hidden` is so *magically useful* in this instance is [explained here](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats).

---

`display: table-cell` is another option, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Khmhk/1/

This [works in IE8+](http://caniuse.com/css-table) and all modern browsers:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <label for="test">Label</label>
    <span><input name="test" id="test" type="text" /></span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%
}
label {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap
}
span {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 0 0 5px
}
input {
    width: 100%
}
```

Comment: The `overflow: hidden` suggestion is pure [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) witchcraft. I love you. I'll never fully understand CSS

Comment: I just want to add that for this to work, it appears, the element with the float has to appear before the <span> (with the overflow: hidden) in the DOM. This is a wonderful css solution in all though, thanks!

Comment: Is there any specific reason for using a span display:block versus just using a div with overflow:hidden on it?

Comment: @PJH: No, not really. Either is fine, it comes down to what you think is more semantic HTML.

Comment: The link explaining the `overflow: hidden` magic is down, but future generations can see it [here on Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618153020/http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/?#making-room-for-floats)

Answer (score 0):

That still works for me, but ftr this is how Bootstrap 3 does it (thanks to [@morten.c's answer to "Bootstrap full-width text-input within inline-form"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22774870/1241736)). Don't know if it's harder to break than @thirtydot's, or anything. But here it is, and [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enry/hf6wktkj/) that also gives a basic example of how to deal with a narrow-screen break point.

HTML:

```
<form class="responsive">
    <input type="text" placeholder="wide input..."/>
    <span>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </span>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
form.responsive, form.responsive * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px !important; /* specify a height */
}
form.responsive {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;

    /* just to be safe */
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
form.responsive > input {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    display: table-cell;
}
form.responsive span {
    position: relative;
    width: 1%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
form.responsive span input {
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: -1px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    overflow: visible;
}
```