# What would be the correct way to insert a form in HTML, in such a way that it's field labels are equally distanced from the input field?

Tags: html, css, w3c

Previously i have been using `<table>` tag in order to structure a form in such a way that we a nice formatted form so that each label and field is on line with eachother like the following:

```
Email:       [############]
Password:    [############]
```

However there's a semantic problem here, a form is not exactly table data. So where a table is graphically suiting, its not on a semantic level.

What would be the proper way to structure a form so it's also graphically pleasing as well as semantically correct in terms of data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [A List Apart article](http://alistapart.com/article/prettyaccessibleforms) does exactly that.

It uses semantically correct tags, and CSS styling to build a table-less form with stable margins. In a nutshell, it uses `label` tags to display the text, and gives them fixed widths to make the form fields start at the same horizontal position.

For a solution with flexible dimensions, see [Fluid input elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120066/fluid-input-elements).

Comment: the only trouble with this that tables DO provide, is if you wanted it to be autosized, and not fixed width.

Comment: @netbrain yeah, tables offer some unique layouting capabilities that can't be reproduced with CSS (except for the IMO incredibly silly `display: table` workaround). Flexible width can be done with CSS though, this should give you what you need: [Fluid input elements](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7120066)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<fieldset>` then customizing your CSS for a better look.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Login</legend>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
    <br />
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
    <br />
</fieldset>
```