# flexible width for HTML input element

Tags: html, css

How do I make the width of HTML input element to be flexible and matching exactly the width of the string value it contains?

Comment: Float it or change it's `display` property.

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120066/fluid-input-elements

Comment: I don't think either of those other comments provide what you're looking for (input width to match its value), but it looks like it's been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392493/adjust-width-of-input-field-to-its-input [for what it's worth, Lyth's answer on that question feels best to me]

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is not possible with only CSS. But you may find a lot of JS solutions online. An easy - but not so elegant - solution to this is to use a `span` and use the `contenteditable` attribute and style it to look like an input:

```
 <span contentEditable="true">Placeholder</span>
```

[see the reference in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable)

Of course, it won't behave as an input, so you'll also have to do a workaround for this too.