# Responsive input fields in CSS - fluid width?

Tags: css, forms, input

I'm trying to make the following sign up box fluid responsive in CSS.

Here is an example: http://cssdesk.com/aYLwW

I would like the input field width to be "flexible" and shrink depending on the page.

You can see from the example when I shrink the window, the button eventually drops down below the input field.

With this in mind, **what should I set my input#iiihuu-iiihuu field width to be** to allow the input field to gracefully resize without any *bumpage*?

Many thanks for any pointers :-D

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6938900/681807

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give a `min-width:550px;` to the div containing the text-box and button. Your control will not break then.

Working ex. here http://cssdesk.com/dUjxF

As the definition says min-width sets a min-width to the element, it doesn't go below that size under any circumstances.

Comment: Thank you, Ashwin. Is there a way to butt the input field up with the button? You'll notice that the button still drops below the input field. Should I remove the `width: 450px` declaration? Thanks again

Comment: @mcgarriers Oops posted the wrong link, changed it, have a look again. http://cssdesk.com/dUjxF

Comment: your cssdesk link doesnt actually make the input field responsive. Typing in the box, results in the text stopping a portion of thw way accross. Your contained dev is responsive - misleading.

Comment: The OP is satisfied with the solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the css widths to percent based. 
 [See here](http://cssdesk.com/RvQwN)