# CSS: How to shadow a field like this?

Tags: css, formatting, textinput

I am trying to style a text input field. So far, I tried to use borders and images as background but that's not a scalable solution. How could I style an input field like the one in the image below?

[image]

Comment: [This](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/) will help you

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Done any research? Look at using a gradient for the border along with an inner `box-shadow`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361075/responsive-input-fields-in-css-fluid-width  -- Possible duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use CSS3 `box-shadow` property. Example:

```
input[type=text] {
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 2px black;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Agree with @Morpheus.
Also you can use 2 shadows at the same time:

```
input[type=text] {
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px 2px #000, inset 0 -2px 2px 2px #fff;
}
```