# How to make an input field have 100% width minus the width of the submit button?

Tags: css, forms, input, resize

I have a very basic single input field with a 'submit' button alongside it. The search button has a fixed width of 104 pixels. Both are wrapped together with total width 50% of the browser viewport. It is my plan to allow the input field to enlarge as the browser window enlarges.

At the moment, for my specific browser window, I am having to fix the width of the input field to spread from the left of the wrapper to the left of the submit button. However, as I resize the window, it (obviously) doesn't adjust accordingly, and hence leaves a white space gap.

I have not found an answer to this question anywhere else. I am well aware that usually a width of 100% with a right padding of 104px will solve this kind of issue with other in-line elements. HOWEVER, the issue here is that the button cannot seem to sit above the padding, and instead moves to a new line.

How may I resolve this? Thanks!

EDIT:
Here's what I have so far. Visit jsfiddle.net/nWCT8/
The whole wrapper needs to be centered, and it needs to have majority browser support (although I don't mind if IE6 won't work with it). For this reason, I don't think 'calc' is quite suitable.

Comment: Do you have set a `height`for the `button` and the `input` or do you need to have a solution that works with the default height, that is set by the system?

Comment: The height is fixed at 37px.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938900/css-input-take-remaining-space/27413796#27413796

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you have a fixed height, you could use `absolute` position to achieve this (If you don't require to support IE 6)

**EDIT** update my answer base on your jsfiddle, but I only could test it in current Chrome, Safari and FF right now.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nWCT8/1/)

To get auto enlarging work proper with FF you need to use a wrapper around it and the `input` needs to have a width of `100%`. To prevent the padding of the `input` elements to be added to the `width` the following css rules needs to be use:

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
```

`box-sizing` is supported by: IE 8+, Chrome, Opera 7+, Safari 3+, Firefox

**EDIT**
Styling `input` elements is typically problematic because of their `padding` and `margin`.
To have the result you want to achieve without the css3 `calc` feature you need to do the following steps:

1. Define the height to the surrounding `.form-wrapper`  and set its `position` to `relative` so that this element is responsible for the position `absolute` of the elements it contains.
2. Wrap a container (`.input-wrapper`) around the the `input` element, defining its position as `absolute` with `left:0px`, `top:0px`, `bottom:0px` and `right:[the width of your button]`  that way the wrapper always has a distance of the `width of the button` to the right side.
3. Set the `width` and `height` of the `input` element to `100%`. To prevent the padding of the `input` element to be added to the `width` you need to set the `box-sizing` to `border-box`.
4. Set the position of the `button` to `absolute` with `top:0px`, `bottom:0px` and `right:0` and setting the width to `width: [width of your button]`

Comment: Thank you for trying, but unfortunately this doesn't work for me.

It may also be of interest that I need to center the whole wrapper.

Comment: @DarkOwl edited to have a width of `70%` and center (with demo link). What does not work for you?

Comment: Using your jsFiddle link, when I drag to resize the output window, the wrapper resizes but the input field does not. I need the input field to touch against the button.

PS. 70% was a bad an example - I'm really using around 50%.

Comment: @DarkOwl updated that answer one more time ;) please check if the fiddle now works for you i'll add further explanations.

Comment: Thanks! That's near-enough perfect. In Firefox, I can see a small, constant gap of approx 5px between the button and the input field, so perhaps we could remove that?

Comment: @DarkOwl Thats because i set the `right` of `.input-wrapper` to `110px` instead  of `104px`. You can change it to have the gap size you want.

Comment: Aha, great. This works very nicely. The only changes I can see are the border-box lines. What do they do specifically? EDIT: I've just found out from http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp.

Comment: @DarkOwl added some details, i hope it explains it enough so that you understand what it is done.

Comment: That's very clear, thank you. If I could up-vote you twice, I would :)

Comment: Modified the code in this answer to be much more simple: [jsfiddle.net/nWCT8/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/nWCT8/4/)

Answer (score 9):

The chosen answer works fine, however, it's overly complicated. Rewrote the answer to be MUCH simpler:

HTML:

```
<div class="halfWidth">
    <div class="input-wrapper">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Input text here"/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.halfWidth {
    width:50%;
}
.input-wrapper {
    margin-right:100px;
}
input {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box; /* ie8 */
    -khtml-box-sizing: border-box; /* konqueror */
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* css3 rec */
}
```

View example at:
http://jsfiddle.net/nWCT8/4/

Comment: gotta respect the konqueror support!

Answer (score 6):

For newer browsers that support CSS3, you could use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

```
width: calc(100% - 50px); // change 50px to width of button
```

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="search" />
    <input type="button" value="Search" id="button" />
    <br class="clear: both;" />
</div>
```

css:

```
 * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

}

div {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;    
    padding: 5px;
    background: grey;      
}

#search {
    width: calc(100% - 110px);        
    float: left; 
}

#button {
    width: 104px;
    float: left;    
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sDfuU/)